# How to show html elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create drop down lists when the submit button is pressed. This will go through a while loop to make diffrent number of lists. I currently have the following code but it dosen't work as intended.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getvalue() {
                number = document.getnumber.input.value;
                document.getElementById("result").value = number;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function generatedropdown() {
                while (i < number) {
                    html = '<select name="select" id="i">';
                    html += '<option>Test 1</option>';
                    html += '<option>Test 2</option>';
                    html += '<option>Test 3</option>';
                    html += '<option>Test 4</option>';
                    html += '<option>Test 5</option>';
                    html += '</select>';

                    innerHTML = html;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <form name="getnumber">Input number:
            <input type="text" name="input">
            <input type="button" value="Next" onClick="getvalue()">
        </form>
        <form id="showlists">Number entered:
            <input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly">
            <input type="button" value="Show lists" onClick="generatedropdown()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I've changed the code to this but still no luck.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getvalue() {
 number = document.getnumber.input.value;
 document.getElementById("result").value = number; 
} 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
function generatedropdown() {
html = '<select name="select" id="i">';
while (i < number)  {            
html+='<option>Test 1</option>';
html+='<option>Test 2</option>';
html+='<option>Test 3</option>';
html+='<option>Test 4</option>';
html+='<option>Test 5</option>';        
i++;
}
html+='</select>';
document.getElementById("my-output").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>


<form name="getnumber">
Input number: <input type="text" name="input">
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="getvalue()">
</form>


<form id="showlists">
Number entered: <input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly">     
<input type="button" value="Show lists" onClick="generatedropdown()">
<div id="my-output">Generated List:</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.innerHTML` on elements only, like so:

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'This is my output';
```

Now, your `body` will be filled with some content. In case you want to put it in an other element, like a `div`, you have to create that `div` first...

```
<div id="my-output"></div>
```

Then get it and apply the content:

```
document.getElementById('my-output').innerHTML = 'This is my output';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = '<select name="select" id="i">';
while (i < number)  {            
    html+='<option>Test 1</option>';
    html+='<option>Test 2</option>';
    html+='<option>Test 3</option>';
    html+='<option>Test 4</option>';
    html+='<option>Test 5</option>';        
    i++;
}
html+='</select>';
document.getElementById('your_element_id').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong, first of all you have to call `getvalue()` before calling `generatedropdown()`, then, instead of `innerHTML = html;` use `document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').innerHTML = html;`